# After updating, the resolution is 1024x768 instead of 1920x1080

Tags: display-resolution

I used the pc this morning, and Ubuntu 18.10 said there are updates, almost 180 megabytes, and now (after restarting a few times) I cannot get back the standard 1920x1080. (AMD Ryzen 2200g, D-SUB connector)

I have been on Linux less than a week, so I have no idea what to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming you are using an Nvidia graphics card, it's likely that update that caused the problem.

Try removing (back it up first) `/home/youruser/.config/monitors.xml` and restart your PC. It will re-initialize that file.

Comment: There is no Nvidia card, just the Ryzen + ASRock motherboard. I'm trying to find your file.

Comment: There is no monitors.xml

Comment: After removing the plug of the monitor from the power strip, I got back the 1920x1080. So, it looks like a monitor problem, not an Ubuntu problem. I hope it will stay this way.